# What are the good resources for database monitoring?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, monitoring

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of some good resources (web sites, technical articles/journals, books, etc.) related to database monitoring/performance?

I am looking to write a paper that explores what kinds of statistics are useful in database monitoring, and to whom they are useful for.

So, I figured I'd ask the experts ...

(In my research, I will be focusing mostly on a PostgreSQL database, but I am looking to gather resources on many different databases).

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about PostgreSQL, but I've found [www.sql-server-performance.com](http://www.sql-server-performance.com) to be a wonderful resource on (MS SQL Server) database tuning.

Here's a page on that site that lists links to various performance-related topics.
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/all_main.aspx

You may be able to apply some of the practices discussed here to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3):

ConSol-plugins are the de-facto standard when it comes to database monitoring with Nagios:

[Oracle](http://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_oracle_health)

[MySQL](http://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_mysql_health)

[MS SQL Server](http://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_mssql_health)

[DB2](http://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_db2_health)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a question with a proper answer because your question tries to cover entire database programming domain in one question.

In most cases the database providers release a good set of tools for monitoring analysis purposes. Example : Oracle. You may use them as well.

And a simple google search gave me a hundreds of good resources that seems to be comply with your question.

[Example](http://www.monitortools.com/databases/)